# Separate application server and database server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I was wondering what to do if an application has a heavy load of database queries.

I am using a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and currently (development time) I am running the SQL Server on the same machine as the ASP.NET application. Everything is fine. The connection is made via loopback interface (localhost), so there is no speed impact at all. There is no physical network.

What happens if the RAM usage is very high because of the SQL Server in production mode? Would it be better to separate the application machine from the database machine?

But if so, the connection has to be done via a real network interface instead of a pseudo loopback interface. Is there any speed impact in this case? Does it result in a latency because of the introduction of a physical network?

Typically I would rent 2 root servers from a hosting provider. One for the application, one for the database with huge ram. How do they communicate with each other? Do both have local IP adresses to get a fast interconnection? Both machines from the same provider.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good question. I would probably receive a superior answer if migrated to [server fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 3):

If you have two servers: a database and app server, then you should set them up so that the database server has 2 network connections (same for the app server). One of those connections is for the private network, the other is public. The app server should talk to the db over the private network. This is a typical implementation and it will be fast. In your application's configuration file, you would set up the connection string to point to the database server's private IP. The public network connection on your database machine should be locked down so that only remote desktop, ping, and maybe the ssh ports are open. On the app server, the public network should have the same ports open and additionally port 80 so it can serve http requests.

Answer (score 1):

hotSauce.Open's has already answered most of your questions, but in any case:

> What happens if the ram-usage is very high because of the sql-server
>   in production mode?

The website's performance will drop, hard, everytime a query is needed.
You could try to ease the load by using Memcached or Redis, for instance. The application itself may need some tweaking also in order to maximize the system's resources (eg: minimize the number of requests, make sure you get swap all "select *" for the specific data you need).

> Would it be better to separate the application-machine from the
>   database-machine?

As mentioned, there are several things you can do before separating the two. In any case, if you're really expecting a high traffic load then running the application on a different server will certainly prove useful (although more expensive...). If it's worth it or not, that's entirely up to your requirements.

Comment: To build on Hal's comment: It's important to note that you _want_ sql server to be using memory. This allows sql server to store a cache as much of the database as it can without starving the OS. This makes queries faster. It will also cache intelligently. If a particular query occurs more frequently than others, it will cache the data needed to handle to query in memory increasing performance. This is ultimately why people opt for a 2 server solution.